# How to store Data from java.util.Scanner ; How to accept input dealing with time

Tags: java, time, java.util.scanner

I am trying to use the Scanner to grab time information. So it is a personal workout tracker that I can insert the time it took for me to complete a certain workout.

All the information that the `Scanner` picks up will need to be stored on a spread sheet. how can I do this

Full code http://ideone.com/wYgTc

```
import java.util.Scanner;

  // How to arrange the answers to the questions … only if answered “yes” if answered         //“no” insert a zero

class WorkOutTracker{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.print(“Did you swim today? “)

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner (System.in);

        DYSwim =  myScanner.nextLine();

        if(DYSwim = = “yes”){

            System.out.println(“How many laps did you swim? “);

            LapNum = myScanner.nextInt();


             // how to scan for time.

            System.out.println(“Did you Time yourself? “);

            DYTime =  myScanner.nextLine();

            if (DYTime = = “yes”){

                System.out.println(“How long did you swim for? “);

                SwimTime = myScanner.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the code you linked too will work fine for parsing seconds...

As for spreadsheets you can interact with Excel spreadsheets using this api: http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/

I've used it before and although it's a little dated it should be fine for your use.